# Java&JFreeChart - How to set a JFreeChart's ChartPanel resize with it's container ( say JPanel )?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jfreechart

I just found that when i add a ChartPanel to a JFrame, the ChartPanel will resize to fit the frame as the JFrame dragged larger or smaller. However, when i add the ChartPanel to a JPanel, the JPanel's size( width and height ) changes to fit the JFrame as the JFrame resized. But the ChartPanel just keeps it's dimensions, leaving the enlarged JPanel a lot of empty space. How to make ChartPanel resize with it's container in GUI?

Here is my sample codes :

1. This case the chart resize with the JFrame

> ```
> ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(createWhateverChart());
> JFrame frame = new JFrame();
> frame.add(chartPanel);
> ```

1. In the case, i add the ChartPanel to JPanel first, for ease of management and update the chart but the ChartPanel doesn't resize with the JPanel/JFrame.

> ```
> ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(createWhateverChart());
> JPanel panel = new JPanel("Who cares");
> panel.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
> JFrame frame = new JFrame();
> frame.add(panel);
> ```

Comment: which layout manager are you using for the JPanel?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), up_to JPanel holds JFreeChart, plaint code about contianers, without implementations for JFreeChart

Comment: re Heisenbug : for JPanel case, BorderLayer. ChartPanel added with BorderLayout.CENTER

Comment: @Biscuitz: try use BoxLayout/FlowLayout instead, or post an SSCCE like suggested mKorbel.

Comment: re mKorbel : Thanks for your advice. I just think that my codes are not very useful in this discussion. Anyway, i added the codes back.

Comment: The problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: `GridLayout`, shown here, is also helpful for this. You can [answer (or delete) your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/163188).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try my code and it works fine.

Note that :

I have one frame which contains a panelMain, A panelMain contains a subPanel and a subPanel contains ChartPanel.

```
frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));                      
JPanel panelMain = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2));            
ChartPanel chartPanel = createChart();        
JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());   
subPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Consommation"));
subPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));    
subPanel.add(chartPanel);   


panelMain.add(subPanel);        
frame.add(panelMain);        
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

And now when you resize your window application. Your chartPanel will resized automatically. Hope this helps.